# Harmonizing local and global definitions of discriminant ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I began skimming [PLC's 8430 handout 5](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8430notes5.pdf) (on chebotarev density and global class field theory), and there are two versions of "discriminant" presented. The set up is that $R$ is a Dedekind domain, $K$ its field of fractions, $L/K$ a separable degree $n$ extension, and $S$ the integral closure of $R$ in $L$.

It's noted that if $R$ is a PID then $S\cong R^n$ as an $R$-module and we may define $\Delta(S/R)$ to be the ideal generated by the discriminant of any chosen integral basis of $S/R$. I can see that this ideal does not depend on choice of basis: $\Delta(x_i')=(\det A)^2\Delta(x_i)$ whenever $\{x_i'\}$ and $\{x_i\}$ are related by the base change matrix $A$, and $\det A\in R^\times$ if $A$ is invertible ($\Leftarrow$ $\{x_i'\}$, $\{x_i\}$ are bases).

If $R$ is not a PID then $S/R$ may not be free. Here are two definitions of $\Delta(S/R)$:

- **Global**: Let $\Delta(S/R)$ be the ideal generated by all discriminants $\Delta(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$, $x_i\in S$.
- **Local**: For primes ${\frak p}\triangleleft R$, we must have $\Delta(S_{\frak p}/R_{\frak p})={\frak p}^{a_{\frak p}}$ for various $a_{\frak p}$. Define $\Delta(S/R)$ as the product of ideals $\prod {\frak p}^{a_{\frak p}}$ over all primes $\frak p$.

I am looking into how these two definitions are equivalent.

For any ideal ${\frak j}\triangleleft R$, we must have ${\frak j}R_{\frak p}={\frak p}^{a_{\frak p}({\frak j})}R_{\frak p}$ for some $a_{\frak p}(\frak j)$, for all primes $\frak p$, and I see that

$${\frak j}=\prod {\frak p}^{e_{\frak p}}\iff \forall{\frak p}~~ {\frak j}R_{\frak p}={\frak p}^{e_{\frak p}}R_{\frak p}$$

Thus it suffices for $\Delta(S_{\frak p}/R_{\frak p})=\Delta(S/R)_{\rm 1st~def}R_{\frak p}$ to hold for each prime $\frak p$. With this last equality, I see how $\supseteq$ holds (since the inclusion $S\hookrightarrow S_{\frak p}$ holds), but I don't see the reverse inclusion $\subseteq$.

Is my understanding correct so far, and what am I missing at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I see it now. It's clear to me that $\Delta(S_{\frak p}/R_{\frak p})\subseteq\overline{\Delta(S/R)_{\rm1st~def}R_{\frak p}}$, where $\overline{X}$ denotes topological closure, since $\det$ is continuous. The ideals of $R_{\frak p}$ are powers of $\frak p$, and each is closed.